# Using pipe in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, processbuilder

I am using ProcessBuilder to run an executable.It works fine.
Now I am in a scenario where I have to give output of 1st executable to the second one.
eg:
exe1 arg1 arg2 | exe2 arg3
and get its InputStream and print to stdout.

so I am writing a small script.sh for that which contains
exe1 arg1 arg2 | exe2 arg3

The following works fine in java:

```
ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder();
    pb.command("/bin/sh","/home/biadmin/Desktop/script.sh");
        Process p=pb.start();
        InputStream in=p.getInputStream();
```

//output successfully printed to stdout.

But when I do the same thing in hadoop environment. I dont get anything in inputstream. I need to work this same thing in hadoop. Any suggestions/advise appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the output from `p.getErrorStream()` to see what errors are coming from your process?  My guess is that when distributed, your script does not exist on the other machines in the cluster.

Comment: yes i checked but nothing is coming in errorstream also. I am running it in pseudodistributed mode.